# Minimum number of groups with recursive grouping a set of objects with their properties

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, np

Suppose we have a set of `n` similar objects having `m` properties `{p1, ..., pm}`. We group these items with property `p1`. Then inside each group, we again group items with property `p2`. We continue grouping of sub-groups with the next property, recursively. If we want to get the minimum number of groups, we may search it by grouping items with all permutations of properties in `O(m!)`.
Is this problem NP-complete? Is there a well-known problem in computer science similar to this problem? or is there a polynomial time solution to find the best order of properties for partitioning to get minimum number of groups?

Comment: Please share what you tried so far. There is no use in just posting your homework, try asking specific questions on where you got stuck trying to solve this (or trying to start solving).

Comment: This is not my homework!! I am trying to solve a problem and in one part of my solution, I reached this problem. I searched NP-complete known problems, but unfortuantely I couldn't reduce this problem to one of them. I just want a help to find a similar known problem in CS field. Thnkx